# Rstudio built in Reformat code vs addin formatR tidy_source()

Tags: r, rstudio, formatr

I learnt that there are two ways to nicely format R code in RStudio. One listed under `Code -> Reformat code`. The other is @yihui `(formatR:tidy_r source code)` which in current Version 0.99.893 of Rstudio, can be added as an addin. I noticed that, the in-built `Reformat code` formats the code to new line every time it encounters a comma `,`( Imagine if you have a list of 10 parameters for some function, you will have 10 lines). However, I personally like @yihui `tidy_r`. So my questions are

1) How to make formatR as a default in Rstudio ?

2) Has anyone noticed errors while using formatR when run on Rshiny apps ? When I run this as an Addin on my shiny code, I get the error below...

```
Warning: Error in base::parse: <text>:81:1: unexpected symbol
80: invisible(".BeGiN_TiDy_IdEnTiFiEr_HaHaHa.HaHaHa_EnD_TiDy_IdEnTiFiEr")
81: invisible
```

@yihui on his github page mentioned in 2012 that formatR is still not good at dealing with #. is this the case still ?

*update as per comment*

```
query = c(
       "26527521","26711930","26314551","26720421","26715198","26714964"           
     )
```

When the above input is formatted using `Code -> Reformat code`, results the output below

```
query = c("26527521",
          "26711930",
          "26314551",
          "26720421",
          "26715198",
          "26714964")
```

Comment: I never encountered the situation you said where it adds a new line for every comma. What version of RStudio and under what specific situation does that happen?

Comment: updated the Q with the output

Comment: Thanks for the example. It seems that this happens when the line is long, but the line length where this happens is not fixed either...

Comment: BTW you can assign a keyboard shortcut to the `formatR` addin in Tools>Global options>Code>Editing>Modify keyboard shortcuts. And I encountered the same error when formatting Shiny apps.

Comment: Yeah. That is what bothering me as well. I would prefer `formatR`. But, it throws an error for shiny apps. And, I don't like the way `Code -> Reformat code` does the formatting. Basically, I have 2 options to neatly format R code, and neither works for my need.